# Passing Arguments in C++ from build File in Sublime Text3

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext3

I wanted to pass arguments to my C++11 code. I do have the build file for the Sublime Text3. But Unable to understand it and modify it to pass my arguments.

I compile my code on OS X, terminal as
"g++ -std=c++11 code.cpp -o code inputFile.csv 8 1000 outFile.csv"

How to modify the following build file to accommodate this arguments:

```
{
     "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++11", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++11 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And what does variants in this stands for?